What are the "tricks" in machine learning?
I have come across a few different "tricks" in machine learning methodology, which I list below along with my rudimental understandings.

The Kernel Trick:
This is used in Support Vector Machines (SVMs) and other algorithms (eg. Kernel Ridge Regression) to enable them to operate in a high-dimensional space without explicitly computing the coordinates of the data in that space. It involves using a kernel function to compute the dot product of the data points in a higher-dimensional space, allowing the algorithm to find a non-linear decision boundary.

The Gumbel-Softmax Trick:
This is a technique used to approximate categorical samples with differentiable operations, enabling gradient-based optimization methods to handle discrete random variables. This approach is particularly useful in neural networks for discrete latent variable models, as it allows for backpropagation through discrete choices. By introducing Gumbel noise to the logits and applying the softmax function, the method produces a continuous, differentiable approximation of categorical distributions, facilitating efficient training of models involving discrete variables.

The Reparameterization Trick:
This technique is primarily used in variational autoencoders (VAEs) and can also be applied in other algorithms involving stochastic processes, such as some generative adversarial networks (GANs). It enables backpropagation through stochastic variables by re-expressing the random variable as a deterministic variable with an added noise term. This allows gradient descent optimization to be effectively applied to models that incorporate probabilistic elements within the model's latent variables or parameters, thus facilitating efficient and stable training.

Log-Sum-Exp Trick: This is used to stabilize the computation of the log of the sum of exponentials, which is common in calculating softmax functions or log probabilities. It helps to avoid numerical overflow and underflow by reformulating the computation.


I noticed that Log-Sum-Exp and the Kernel Trick both have their own tags here on CV.
I am curious about two things. Firstly, what about these methods make them "tricks" ? What is it about them that makes them "tricky" ? English is not my native language so maybe (probably) there is some subtleness about the use of that term here that I haven't got. My basic understanding is that these "methods" are really just that - methods, and I don't really understand why they are called "tricks".
Consulting an English Dictionary I found what might the answer: "a clever or particular way of doing something". I guess that makes some sense. Is that it ?
The problem I have with that explanation is: surely there must be hundreds of other methods that are also very clever ways to solve stubborn. What makes these "tricks" special ?
The second question I have, is what other tricks are commonly utilized in machine learning, and are known as "tricks" in the machine learning community.

Well some techniques are called 'tricks' and others aren't. This seems highly subjective.
